# count occurence of value (tuple set) in dictionary keep original dictionary length in output list/dictionary/ tuple

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples, counter

I've seen this sort question asked many times but unfortunately for me this time it comes with a bit of a twist.

I have a dictionary in the format:

```
name: (job, score)
```

example:

```
dict = {bob: (farmer, 9), sue: (farmer, 9), tim: (farmer, 5), jill, (chef, 8)}
```

now if i use:

```
x =  Counter(x for x in dict.values())
```

I'll get the list as expected (but not what I want):

```
Counter({(farmer,9): 2, (farmer, 5): 1, (chef, 8): 1})
```

what i would really like is to see each name with the occurrences of their job and score like so:

```
Counter({bob:2, sue:2, tim:1, jill:1})
```

which is also to say that I would like the output dictionary length to be the same as the input dictionary length.

Things I can change:

- dictionary could maybe be set of nested tuples? i.e. (bob,(farmer,9)) if this helps?
- wouldn't mind if only list of occurrences were returned i,e 2,2,1,1
- also wouldn't mind being told there's a much better way to do this.

what im trying to do is make occurence the size of my bubble in a bubble chart.
I'd like to be able to extract a list of the same length of occurrences at the same index as described above.

So far I have an equal list of jobs and scores, that third list containing occurrences would help make the graph more clear I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are half way there. Just link your 2 dictionaries and remember to *never named variables after classes*, e.g. use `d` not `dict`.

```
from collections import Counter

d = {'bob': ('farmer', 9), 'sue': ('farmer', 9),
     'tim': ('farmer', 5), 'jill': ('chef', 8)}

x =  Counter(x for x in d.values())

res = Counter({k: x[v] for k, v in d.items()})

# Counter({'bob': 2, 'jill': 1, 'sue': 2, 'tim': 1})
```

Comment: Hi! This is exactly what I was looking for! I have a very similar piece of code elsewhere in what I'm doing but never thought to use it here too. Thanks again for your help! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Your dict omits '' around strings, which would result in an error at runtime. Hence:

```
dict = {'bob': ('farmer', 9), 'sue': ('farmer', 9), 'tim': ('farmer', 5), 'jill': ('chef', 8)}
```

Since the values in your dict are lists in identical format, you can just index them (just like any other list):

```
for k, v in dict.items():
    print(k,v[1])

#OUTPUT:
tim 5
bob 9
jill 8
sue 9
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your answer! Unfortunately its not quite the one I was looking for. I mentioned that I'm trying to get the occurance of the duplicates of the job and score tuple and then have that returned next to the name somehow - format didnt really matter. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score -1):

**First don't use dict as a variable name:**

You can try this approach without importing anything.

```
dict_1 = {'bob': ('farmer', 9),'sue': ('farmer', 9), 'tim': ('farmer', 5), 'jill':('chef', 8)}
```

First group similar values:

```
pre_data={}

for i,j in dict_1.items():
    if j not in pre_data:
        pre_data[j]=[i]
    else:
        pre_data[j].append(i)
```

Now catch the length of count

```
final_result={}
for i,j in pre_data.items():

    if len(j)>1:
        for sub_data in j:


            final_result[sub_data]=len(j)
    else:
        final_result[j[0]]=1
print(final_result)
```

output:

```
{'sue': 2, 'jill': 1, 'tim': 1, 'bob': 2}
```